# Loading php pages with jquery

Tags: php, image-processing

Loading an external php file with jquery is actually easy.  I simply use the load() event.

Like this:

```
$("#someelement").load('somepage.php');
```

Typically it's just fine, until I use the image manipulation functions.

Here's what I put inside somepage.php

```
<?php
$img = 'tmp/someimage.png';
$img = imagecreatefrompng($img);
header('Content-type: image/png');
imagepng($img);
?>
```

When somepage.php is loaded, I get messy code back.  (which I'm not sure what it would be considered)

I'm pretty sure there's a limitation to loading complicated image functions, but I thought I'd ask if there's a workaround.

Comment: If you want to display an image, you can create an `<img>` element with the `src` attribute set to wherever your script is, and it will load the image appropriately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As *@onteria_* pointed out, `.load()` isn't for image data. It's for HTML.

You will have to create an `<img />` tag, set its `src=` attribute, and then append it to your element:

```
$('body').append($('<img id="someelement" />').attr('src', 'somepage.php'));
```

Comment: Totally works! I simply use the html() event and call an <img> with the src pointing to my php page.  It renders just fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print an image, just append `<img src="somepage.php" />` where you want with jQuery.

Since you are trying to load the file like a text, jQuery trying to get the contents of it. Loading an executed php file that echoes texts is one thing, printing images is another.